# iMac will not boot into anything

Tags: imac, startup, sip, single-user, fsck

As the title says, I cannot boot my iMac (late 2012) into anything. I’ve tried everything from booting into Safe Mode, Recovery Mode (and Internet Recovery Mode), doing a diagnostics test (which didn’t work), and resetting NVRAM and SMC; nothing is working. I’m just stuck in a boot loop, the progress bar gets to around 60% and it turns off and reboots. I also have an external hard drive which I boot into to play games but when I try to boot in using the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, I get back to the boot loop.

I’ve tried booting into Single User Mode and trying to run `fsck` but I can't do it because I can't disable SIP. I’m really stuck on what do to. Is there any fix to this, or do I have to take a trip to the Apple Store?

Comment: Based on what you've described and all the troubleshooting you've done, it's quite likely to be some sort of hardware issue, especially because of its age and the fact that the behaviour is replicated when booting from an external drive.